# Why is my powershell multi runspace code taking the same amount of time as my synchronous code?

Tags: multithreading, powershell

To test this code you'll have to fill in the top 2 variables. What I can't understand is why the top code set (psuedo multithreaded) takes the same amount of time to process as the bottom code set (standard synchronous processing)? Using start-jobs I experienced the same thing.

What am I doing wrong with runspaces here?

```
cls

$dagName = "XXXXXXX";
$connectionUri = "XXXXXXX";

Write-Host ([DateTime]::Now).ToString();
Write-Host "";

$time = New-Object system.Diagnostics.Stopwatch  
Start-Sleep 1
$time.Start() 
$system = $time.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds

    $session = new-pssession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $connectionUri;
    import-pssession $session -AllowClobber; 



set-adserversettings -viewentireforest $true;

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null;

if (($dagName -eq $null) -or ($dagName -eq ""))
{
    $dagName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter a dag name", "Dag");
}


$dagObject = Get-DatabaseAvailabilityGroup -Identity $dagName;

$servers = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;
foreach($server in $dagObject.Servers)
{
    $servers.Add($server.ToString()) | Out-Null;
}

$getExchangeServers = @();
$getMailboxDatabases = @();
$getMailboxDatabasesWithStatus = @();
$getWinEvents = @();


$maxThreads = 7

$runspacePool = [RunspaceFactory ]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $maxThreads)
$runspacePool.Open()

$scriptBlock1 = { param($p) $session1 = new-pssession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $connectionUri; import-pssession $session1 -AllowClobber; $getExchangeServers = @(); foreach ($server in $p) { $getExchangeServers += get-exchangeserver $server; } return $getExchangeServers; }
$scriptBlock2 = { param($p) $session2 = new-pssession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $connectionUri; import-pssession $session2 -AllowClobber; $getMailboxDatabases = @(); foreach ($server in $p) { $getMailboxDatabases += Get-MailboxDatabase -Server $server; } return $getMailboxDatabases; }
$scriptBlock3 = { param($p) $session3 = new-pssession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $connectionUri; import-pssession $session3 -AllowClobber; $getMailboxDatabasesWithStatus = @(); foreach ($server in $p) { $getMailboxDatabasesWithStatus += Get-MailboxDatabase -Server $server -Status; } return $getMailboxDatabasesWithStatus; } 

$jobs = @()

$job1 = [powershell ]::Create().AddScript($scriptBlock1 ).AddArgument($servers)
$job1.RunspacePool = $runspacePool
$jobs += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
   Pipe = $job1
   Result = $job1.BeginInvoke()
}

$job2 = [powershell ]::Create().AddScript($scriptBlock2 ).AddArgument($servers)
$job2.RunspacePool = $runspacePool
$jobs += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
   Pipe = $job2
   Result = $job2.BeginInvoke()
}


$job3 = [powershell ]::Create().AddScript($scriptBlock3 ).AddArgument($servers)
$job3.RunspacePool = $runspacePool
$jobs += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
   Pipe = $job3
   Result = $job3.BeginInvoke()
}

Do {

   Write-Host $Jobs.Result.IsCompleted;
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 7

} While ( $Jobs.Result.IsCompleted -contains $false )
Write-Host "All jobs completed!"
Write-Host $Jobs.Result.IsCompleted;


Foreach ($Job in $Jobs)
{
    Write-Host $job.Pipe.EndInvoke($job.Result);
}


$time.Stop();
$totalTime = $time.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds - $system;
[float]$runTimeSeconds = [math]::Round($totalTime/1000, 2);
[float]$runTimeMinutes = [math]::Round($totalTime/60000, 2);
Write-Host 
Write-Host "This function took " $runTimeSeconds.ToString() " seconds (or " $runTimeMinutes.ToString() " minutes) to run";








<# Code set 2#>

Write-Host ([DateTime]::Now).ToString();
Write-Host "";

$time = New-Object system.Diagnostics.Stopwatch  
Start-Sleep 1
$time.Start() 
$system = $time.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds



    $session = new-pssession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri $connectionUri;
    import-pssession $session -AllowClobber; 



set-adserversettings -viewentireforest $true;

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null;

if (($dagName -eq $null) -or ($dagName -eq ""))
{
    $dagName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter a dag name", "Dag");
}


$dagObject = Get-DatabaseAvailabilityGroup -Identity $dagName;

$servers = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;
foreach($server in $dagObject.Servers)
{
    $servers.Add($server.ToString()) | Out-Null;
}

$getExchangeServers = @();
$getMailboxDatabases = @();
$getMailboxDatabasesWithStatus = @();
$getWinEvents = @();


foreach ($server in $servers) { $getExchangeServers += get-exchangeserver $server; } Write-Host $getExchangeServers;
foreach ($server in $servers) { $getMailboxDatabases += Get-MailboxDatabase -Server $server; } Write-Host $getMailboxDatabases;
foreach ($server in $servers) { $getMailboxDatabasesWithStatus += Get-MailboxDatabase -Server $server -Status; } Write-Host $getMailboxDatabasesWithStatus;

$time.Stop();
$totalTime = $time.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds - $system;
[float]$runTimeSeconds = [math]::Round($totalTime/1000, 2);
[float]$runTimeMinutes = [math]::Round($totalTime/60000, 2);
Write-Host 
Write-Host "This second function took " $runTimeSeconds.ToString() " seconds (or " $runTimeMinutes.ToString() " minutes) to run";
```

Comment: How long does it take in each case? And how many servers are we talking about?

Comment: Both take about 11 minutes to process. The dag has 12 servers. I would think the multithreaded time would = (synchronous time/threads) + some overhead time. I think ~5 minutes would be a reasonable expectation?

Comment: Depends on how the Exchange servers process requests from the same client. I'd suggest getting all three sets of information from each server (so, contacting the servers in parallel)

Comment: I've tried both different URI connection values and the same URI connection value and the result is similar.

Comment: No no, instead of 3 jobs/runspaces that connect to all 12 servers, create 12 jobs/runspaces (1 per server), in which you retrieve both the Server, Database and DatabaseStatus objects all at once

Comment: I can try that and would just modify the code I have if my code correct for that? Can you confirm the code above is foundationally  correct before I modify it?